# Thread optimal pool size configuration?

Tags: multithreading, language-agnostic, threadpool, theory

What is the reason of keeping thread pool size equal to the number of processors/cores for CPU-intensive tasks? And why I/O bound tasks should have larger pool size?

Comment: What is the reason of paying for college if you are going to get your assignments done by SO crowd?

Answer (score 2):

There is a *correlation* between the optimal number of threads to the number of **c**entral **p**rocessing **u**nits because a thread can be thought of as a program. Programs requires run time. Run time is provided by a central processing unit.

A producer - consumer analogy would have the program as the consumer and the central processing units as the producer. So theoretically - if a producer (cpu) can handle `T` consumers (threads) and there are `C` producers - the optimal number of consumers would be `T * C`.

Too many threads would cause for too much [context switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) overhead, which is practically wasted cpu time to manage the threads themselves. Too few would cause idle cpus while tasks are still in queue.

I/O **bound** tasks communicate with slow devices (that's the reason they're called I/O bound). While requests are made to a slow device (such as the hard drive), the [scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_%28computing%29#Process_scheduler) can have the cpu run other threads instead of waiting for the device's output.

An analogy for that would be you (the scheduler) ordering food in a restaurant (thread 1) and then sending an SMS to your friend (thread 2). The fact that you're waiting for your food shouldn't deny you of completing other tasks, such as sending the SMS to your friend.

---

To have deeper knowledge about possible optimizations you may want to read about [affinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity) and [scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_%28computing%29).